# Convert string "1" or "0" to bool true or false

Tags: c#, .net

`Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(bool))` return a runtime-error

is there any way to override this behavior?

I would like `Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(bool)) return`true
`Convert.ChangeType("0", typeof(bool))` return `false`

**UPDATE**
reading comments and answers maybe I have not been clear enough

Suppose to have a dictionary of `<object,Type>` where type is the target type

```
foreach (var element in dictionary)
{
   object convVal = Convert.ChangeType(element.Key, element.Value);
}
```

when `element.Key` is `"1"` and `elemen.Value` is `bool` I would like to get `true`

Anyone can give me any suggestions to implement a similar behavior

At least something better that this:

```
 public static class Convert
    {
        public static object ChangeType(object val, Type type)
        {
            if (val is string && type == typeof(bool))
            {

                switch (((string)val).Trim().ToUpper())
                {
                    case "TRUE":
                    case "YES":
                    case "1":
                    case "-1":
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return System.Convert.ChangeType(val, type);
        }
    }
```

Can TypeConverter be the right way?

Please think before to post comments or answers or mark question as duplicated

Comment: Did you bother Googling this?

Comment: What's wrong with Convert.ToBoolean ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205436/convert-toboolean-fails-with-0-value

Comment: @GrantWinney Huh, remembered that one wrong.

Comment: *"is there any way to override this behavior?"* No. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3847463/5265292

Comment: Bad duplicate choice IMO. This question is not how to use alternative code to get a result but whether/how it is possible to make the exact code behave differently in order to get a result.

Comment: @tnw StackOverflow is Google. I googled this and came here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is, that the conversion of `string` to `bool` is supported on the type level, but fails for most string values. This means, that you first have to check for your custom conversion rules before falling back to the default converters. Some of the `CanConvert...` functions will return true, leading to a runtime exception on actual conversion.

So in order to accept any non-zero number string for `true` and zero for `false`, first check numbers separately, then use custom type converters in case they are provided and fall back to the defaults when nothing else is found, you could use the following:

```
static object CustomConvert(object value, Type targetType)
{
    decimal numericValue;
    if ((targetType == typeof(bool) || targetType == typeof(bool?)) && 
        value is string &&
        decimal.TryParse((string)value, out numericValue))
    {
        return numericValue != 0;
    }
    var valueType = value.GetType();
    var c1 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(valueType);
    if (c1.CanConvertTo(targetType)) // this returns false for string->bool
    {
        return c1.ConvertTo(value, targetType);
    }
    var c2 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
    if (c2.CanConvertFrom(valueType)) // this returns true for string->bool, but will throw for "1"
    {
        return c2.ConvertFrom(value);
    }
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType); // this will throw for "1"
}
```

Note I didn't check whether it's useful to try `Convert.ChangeType` after both type converters (From and To) already failed... might as well just throw an exception at this point.

Comment: there is an issue if sting is space or empty on bool type
if(targetType == typeof(bool) || targetType == typeof(bool?))
  {
   value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value?.ToString()) ? 0: Convert.ToInt16(value);
  }

Comment: @PowerMouse same problem for input like `"foobar"`. My solution is not a "TryConvert". It only shows how to support a limited set of additional values that are not covered by `Convert.ChangeType`. If you want to support empty strings, go ahead. But I don't see why I should support empty string but not "foobar" and I don't know whether they should mean true or false in a specific context.

Answer (score 10):

```
bool flag = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32("1"));
```

Comment: Why the Convert.ToInt32? ToBoolean accepts string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SilentStorm read your own link... *"A string that contains the value of either `Boolean.TrueString` or `Boolean.FalseString`"*, so it accepts string as type but it won't process `"1"` into a good result.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
bool x = myString.Equals("1");
```

Comment: Why the `? true : false` part?

Comment: Isn't the `myString.Equals("1")` enough ?

Comment: Why `Equals` and not simply `bool x = str == "1";`?

Answer (score 2):

I think best approach for this situation is using equation like below;

```
string myString = "1";
bool myBool = myString == "1";
```

Comment: This method should compare == "0" or != "0", because you also want "2" or "-1" to be true

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(uint)));
```